# previous username after doing sudo -u sbsh

Tags: perl, unix, sudo

I am using the system as "user1" and I sudo as different user say "sudo -u user2 sbsh" and the execute a perl script.

Is there a way to get the "user1" in the script I am running ?

I used ENV{'USER'}. but it is giving "user2". 'SUDO_USER' is also not working.

Comment: What does it display when you use `SUDO_USER`?

Comment: @AntonH I am getting nothing with SUDO_USER

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried that.. either getting root or user2 or nothing.. But not user1

Comment: @BenjaminW. It is not sujt sudo -u.. it is sudo -u sbsh

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ENV{'SUDO_USER'}`.

Example:

```
$ sudo perl -E 'say for $ENV{USER}, $ENV{SUDO_USER}'
```

Comment: "user2" and " ".  I am not getting "user1" at all

Comment: My `sudo --version` says `1.8.16`. What says yours?

Comment: 1.8.6p7 is mine